# in New Terminal window : count 1 to 10

Tags: bash

Open new Terminal and count 1 to 10 within it.

```
terminal -e "for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done;"
```

result:

```
  3
  3
  3
  3
  3...
```

why is it doing that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of double quotes - they make variables to be interpreted in current shell, the one that executes terminal command. You got 3 apparently for the reason your $i is defined in your shell so before.
Use single quotes to get expected result.